# Function of three variables: find optimum value of one variable in a region determined by the other two

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to find the optimal value of `h` for which the absolute values of `f[x, t, h]` are near to zero in the region of `x ∈ [0, 1]` and `t ∈ [0, 1`.

For an example take:

```
f[x_, t_, h_] = 
  1 + E^x + 1.0042043426424887` E^x h t^0.99` + 
  E^x h (1.0042043426424887`(1 + h) t^0.99` + 0.5092731902056415` h t^1.98`) + 
  E^x h *
    (1.0042043426424885`(1.` + 1.` h)^2 t^0.99` + 
    h (1.018546380411283` + 1.018546380411283` h) t^1.98` + 
    0.17304492757995624` h^2 t^2.9699999999999998`)
```

Comment: `h == -1.688` is a good starting point as seen from `Manipulate[Plot3D[Abs[f[x, t, h]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}], {{h, -1.688}, -2, -1}]`. It is unclear, however, what "optimal" means. Are you minimizing the $L^1$-norm, $L^\infty$-norm, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
sol = Minimize[
  Abs[f[x, t, h]]
  , {x, t, h} ∈ Cuboid[{0, 0, -5}, {1, 1, 3}]
  , Reals
  ]
(* {2.58438*10^-10, {x -> 0.981745, t -> 0.157703, 
  h -> -2.79438}} *)
```

Therefore `h -> -2.79438` gives you the smallest (closest to zero) absolute value of `f[x, t, h]` in the interval $x \in \{0,1\}$,  $t \in \{0,1\}$.

To visualize a cross section along the $x, t, h$ axis around the minimum.

```
Multicolumn[
 Plot[
    #1,
    Evaluate@Sequence[
      {#2[[1]], #2[[2]] - 1, #2[[2]] + 1},
      FrameLabel -> {ToString[#2[[1]]], "f"}
      ]
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , ImageSize -> 200
    ] & @@@ Transpose@{
    Abs[f[x, t, h]] /. Subsets[sol[[2]], {2}],
    Reverse[List @@@ sol[[2, All]]]
    }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]